# how to setup custom command for an linux appliance?

Tags: c, linux

I want to setup an applicance that will have an custom bash prompt where normal linux command will not run. Instead it will run pre-configured command by us.

E.g On booting up appliance will show

> help [On typing this command]
>   show licence
>   show status
>   ....

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom bash prompt by [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library

You can write c code for example :

```
while(1)
{
   command = readline ("# "); ///readline will accept your custom command

   ////Process your command

   add_history (command); ///This will add your command in history

   free (command);

}
```

You need to add this application in /etc/init.d/rcS at last line for executing it at boot time